# Decomposition forms in Frobenius extensions

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields

Let K be a Frobenius extension of Q of degree m. For a prime p, can we determine the decomposition form of p in K? Indeed, there exists a theorem due H. Cohen (Advanced topics in Computational number Theory, H. Cohen, Prop. 10.1.26) which gives decomposition form of p in dihedral extensions of Q with degree 2q, where q is an odd prime. Is Cohen's result generalizable to Frobenius extensions?

Comment: Can you recall what is a Frobenius extension?

Comment: A Frobenius extension is an extension whose Galois group is a Frobenius group.

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer I'm extrapolating, but for $\text{Gal}(K/\mathbf{Q}) = D_n$ I think we can use Artin reciprocity to show the non-abelian representations are induced from Hecke characters of $F = K^{C_n} = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{\Delta})$ and use it to make the splitting of rational primes explicit. The same could work with higher solvable groups, but using class field theory more than once.

Answer (score 2):

The arithmetic of Frobenius extensions (decomposition, ramification, unit group, L-functions, class numbers etc.) is covered in Steckel, [Arithmetik in Frobeniuserweiterungen](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01165797).

Comment: I am very grateful for your helpful answer